# Is there any documentation for ServiceStack.Text.JSConfig with regard to MonoTouch AOT helpers?

Tags: xamarin.ios, servicestack, aot

Is there any documentation for ServiceStack.Text.JSConfig with regard to MonoTouch AOT helpers?

I Found this... 
[ServiceStack JIT Error on MonoTouch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11385586/servicestack-jit-error-on-monotouch)
and I've had a look at the code but there are no comments and frankly it is a bit mysterious.

From my understanding of the AOT process all one needs to do to make sure a type/method is emitted is to have that type/method in one's source where the compiler thinks it may be used/called. It is not necessary to actually use/call anything at run time. The whole point of AOT is that it is a compile-time process. Consequently putting the use/call inside a method that is not used will work as long as the optimizer does not remove it.

I've been trying to use ServiceStack.Text.JsConfig.RegisterTypeForAot(); (in an unused method) to cure my AOT issues but have run into other weird issues when I have too many calls to it. See other question...

[Calling ServiceStack.Text.JsConfig.RegisterTypeForAot<T>(); with MonoTouch causes SIGSEGV on startup on device](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13796704/calling-servicestack-text-jsconfig-registertypeforaott-with-monotouch-cause)

Could I maybe be using the RegisterTypeForAot() method wrongly?
What do the other methods do? RegisterForAot() and InitAot()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no documentation about `JsConfig.InitForAot()` other than what's already [in-line in the JsConfig](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.Text/blob/master/src/ServiceStack.Text/JsConfig.cs#L388), i.e:

> Provide hint to MonoTouch AOT compiler to pre-compile generic classes
>   for all your DTOs. Just needs to be called once in a static
>   constructor.

You should only have to call the `JsConfig.InitForAot()` stub and a `JsConfig.RegisterTypeForAot<T>()` for each type to let the MonoTouch compiler know what generic code needs to be pre-generated ahead of time so that all the code is available for generic reflection. If you run into a problem submit a small stand-alone test case with the issue on the [GitHub project issues](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.Text/issues) so we can see if there are any work around that can be done.